# How to create route request?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new in angularjs. recently I have practiced angular so my starting point is routing. & I see from this link  /home/rafat/Downloads/Wildlife-Night.tmTheme

my route provider file looks like below.

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);

sampleApp .config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/addOrder', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/add-order.html',
        controller: 'AddOrderController'
      }).
      when('/showOrders', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/show-orders.html',
        controller: 'ShowOrdersController'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/addOrder'
      });
  }]);
```

& the HTML ,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>AngularJS Routing example</title>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="sampleApp">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#AddNewOrder"> Add New Order </a></li>
                <li><a href="#ShowOrders"> Show Order </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

but it does not work; how do I solve this problem?

Comment: Find the solution from here- http://jsfiddle.net/cmckeachie/mtV62/light/

Comment: make sure your controllers are defined .

Answer (score 1):

i think instead of this:

```
<li><a href="#AddNewOrder"> Add New Order </a></li>
<li><a href="#ShowOrders"> Show Order </a></li>
```

you should have:

```
<li><a href="#/addOrder"> Add New Order </a></li>
<li><a href="#/showOrders"> Show Order </a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `a href` attributes are wrong in the `nav`. Should be:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#/addOrders"> Add New Order </a></li>
    <li><a href="#/showOrders"> Show Order </a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Move your script tags up to the head
2. your module name is phonecatApp but in html: ng-app="sampleApp"?